# MySQL simple stored procedure calling another simple one and never ending

Tags: mysql, combinations

Trying to calculate the sum of n x k-combinations (ie. non-ordered) for m elements.

To calculate a k-combination, I need to create a function which calculates factorial.

The code is quite simple, and works :

```
BEGIN
DECLARE factorial INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE counter INT;
SET counter = m;  --  m is my variable
factorial_loop: REPEAT
SET factorial = factorial * counter;
SET counter = counter - 1;
UNTIL counter = 1
END REPEAT;
RETURN factorial;
END
```

Then I want to create anothe simple function adding the k-combinations until a given threshold.

Exemple : I want to know how many k-combinations exist for 7 elements from 4 elements.

It's :

- the combination of 7 elements within 7 elements = 1 unordered combination
- the combination of 6 elements within 7 elements = 7 unordered combination
- the combination of 5 elements within 7 elements = 21 unordered combination
- the combination of 4 elements within 7 elements = 35 unordered combination

TOTAL = 64

For this I created a second stored procedure, calling the first one.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE tempo INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE counter2 INT;
SET counter2 = X;  --  X is the number of elements, in the example 7
combisum_loop: REPEAT
SET tempo = tempo + factorial(x)/(factorial(counter2)*factorial(x-counter2));  --  the mathematical formula for k-combinations
SET counter2 = counter2 - 1 ;
UNTIL counter2 = Y  --  Y is the thresold, in the example 4
END REPEAT;
RETURN tempo;
END
```

Problem : calling the second function with even these small numbers never ends. What am I doing wrong ?

PS: some thoughts :

- if I remplace the mathematical function by the number 1, it returns 4 (the correct result)
- if I replace the mathematical formula by a unique call to the factorial function, it works ! (ie. it finishes, but of course that's not the result I want to achieve)
- if I create a k-combination function with the whole formula but without the loop it also works !!!
- if I call the k-combination function within my loop, it fails

So the problem seems to be when I have both a loop and several (indirect) calls to the - indeed simple - factorial function.

NB: tried to modify the second stored procedure in order to avoid the factorial(0) like suggested by @nbk, but this still fails :

```
BEGIN
DECLARE tempo INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE counter2 INT;
SET counter2 = X-1;
voila3_loop: REPEAT
SET tempo = tempo + factorial(x)/(factorial(counter2)*factorial(x-counter2));
SET counter2 = counter2 - 1 ;
UNTIL counter2 = Y
END REPEAT;
RETURN tempo;
END
```

the first iteration should be tempo = 1 + factorial(7)/(factorial(6)*factorial(7-6)); and should definitely work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides minor problems in  your code.

your first round of your second function starts with a divison by NULL

because `factorial(0) =0`

I am unfamiliar with the formula you are using

And so the function doesn't run at all.

so the formula doesn't seem to be right.

> ```
> CREATE Function factorial(m INT)
> RETURNS BIGINT unsigned DETERMINISTIC
> BEGIN
> DECLARE factorial BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;
> DECLARE counter INT;
> SET counter = m;  --  m is my variable
> factorial_loop: REPEAT
> SET factorial = factorial * counter;
> SET counter = counter - 1;
> UNTIL counter <= 1
> END REPEAT;
> RETURN factorial;
> END
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT factorial(4)/(factorial(4) * factorial(0))
> ```
>
> ```
> | factorial(4)/(factorial(4) * factorial(0)) |
> | -----------------------------------------: |
> |                                       null |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT factorial(4)/(factorial(3) * factorial(1))
> ```
>
> ```
> | factorial(4)/(factorial(3) * factorial(1)) |
> | -----------------------------------------: |
> |                                     4.0000 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT factorial(4)/(factorial(2) * factorial(2))
> ```
>
> ```
> | factorial(4)/(factorial(2) * factorial(2)) |
> | -----------------------------------------: |
> |                                     6.0000 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT factorial(4)/(factorial(1) * factorial(3))
> ```
>
> ```
> | factorial(4)/(factorial(1) * factorial(3)) |
> | -----------------------------------------: |
> |                                     4.0000 |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE Function factor(x INT)
> RETURNS BIGINT unsigned DETERMINISTIC
> BEGIN
> DECLARE tempo BIGINT UNSIGNED  DEFAULT 0;
> DECLARE counter2 INT;
> SET counter2 = x;  --  X is the number of elements, in the example 7
> combisum_loop: REPEAT
> SET @a := counter2;
> SET tempo = tempo + factorial(x)/(factorial(counter2)*factorial(x-counter2));  --  the mathematical formula for k-combinations
>
> SET counter2 = counter2 - 1 ;
> UNTIL counter2 <= Y  --  Y is the thresold, in the example 4
> END REPEAT;
> RETURN tempo;
> END
> ```

> ```
> SELECT factor(4)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT @a
> ```
>
> ```
> | @a |
> | -: |
> |  4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1418fed08d66428f594e596ad79cf41d)*

Comment: wow you're so right !!! i made sure to count backwards (from 7 to 0) and i forgot the factorial(x-counter2)... thanks lot

Comment: mmmhhh modified the query so it starts at X-1 instead of X, so there's no factorial(0) - because it starts after and stops before - and it's still failing...

Comment: no the code runs https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5cd70a13a5e0f02b939da72c874d378e

Comment: well except the data types i saw no differences in the codes but when i copy/paste yours it works, so be it !   ;-)

Comment: no besides the datatypes there is a smaler than counter/counter2 else it will fail ;)